# IIS Rewrite Regex

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have struggling with IIS rewrite regex for awhile now. All I have to do is to remove the entire text after the question mark in the url below:

http://www.blah.com/Pages/Content.aspx?id=n%2fWA2PJCJXXnu8mvdC0jXQ%3d%3d&ln=Gy7UlI4cSJE94Wa2qudbFQ%3d%3d

so this url becomes http://www.blah.com/Pages/Content.aspx.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below is a very basic rule and will need to be amended to support your page/content, but you can simply make the page redirect to itself and add `appendQueryString="false"`.

```
<rule name="Redirect - without QS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: I think you might want to break it in 2, where the first part would be captured this way: `([^\?]*)\?.*`, this way you can use the {R:1} without any problem.